# Как получить случайные записи в Entity Framework из бд?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq

Сабж.
Нужно получить к примеру 3 случайных уникальных записей. 
Вот что я придумал. Массив заполнен псевдослучайными числами для примера

```
int[] rnd = new int[3] { 5, 8, 12 };

db.Films.Skip(rnd[0] - 1).Take(1).Skip(rnd[1] - 1).Take(1).Skip(rnd[2]-1).Take(1) ;
```

И так не работает. Но логика такая, пропускаем элементы до первого нужного в данном случае 4 элемента пропускаем, затем берем 1 элемент потом снова пропускаем и так далее.
В общем вопрос Как получить случайные записи в Entity Framework из бд?

UPD Можно получить все элементы а потом из них выбрать уже по номеру но я думаю как то не целесообразно выбирать из бд тысячи записей что бы получить 3 шуки.

Comment: Если взять один элемент и потом пропустить среди взятых 7 элементов, то уже на этом шаге в выборке ничего не останется

Comment: гуглить linq order by rand - и вот пара подходящих ответов на so: https://stackoverflow.com/q/43414267/5752652 и https://stackoverflow.com/q/9449452/5752652

Answer (score 0):

Используй библиотеку Random, создай случайные числа. Получи три рандомных числа и пытайся вывести записи по ID из базы данных. Проверяй на существование такого ID в базе